# Applying a png mask on a video html/css

Tags: html, css, masking

I am having some issues applying a PNG mask onto a MP4 file. 
Not sure where i am going wrong with this.

The html goes like

```
<html>
<body>
    <video id="wee" autoplay src="dosebotdesigns.com/smoke.mp4">
</body>
</html>
```

and the css reads,

```
#wee {
  mask-image: url(dosebotdesigns.com/test4.png);
}
```

Feel free to check this JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tyd8wggr/

My main goal is to have the png mask the smoke video. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Use the vendor prefix: https://jsfiddle.net/tyd8wggr/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `-webkit-mask-image` for it to work on chrome, but it only works in certain browsers right now.

Answer (score 1):

This tag is experimental and doesn't work in a lot of browsers, see [its compatibility matrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image#Browser_compatibility).  That said, it worked fine* for me in Chrome 55ish by simply adding `-webkit-mask-image: url(http://dosebotdesigns.com/test4.png);` to your existing css.

*(well, "works fine" as in it *displays*, you'll need some tweaks to account for aspect ratio differences between the image and video)

edit: I think you're looking for something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/krot1q67/1/).

Comment: Yes! The actual effect i am going for is the splash page of http://kemuri-tatsuya.com/  (i took their smoke mp4 :p )

Comment: I was thinking of putting the 2 items in a div. I tried to make the border of the image 100%, but apparently thats not a thing in css. Maybe put 2 divs next to my "under construction" image that have black backgrounds?